# Buddhist views on talking with the dead? Is it possible?

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, bardo

In Tibetan Buddhist teaching it is stated that we will be in bardo state for 49 days before rebirth. So during this period we can still communicate with the dead?

What is the Buddhist view on this? Can the dead communicate with the living, for example via chimes (making sound notes that only the family member will know)?
Is it possible or just a joke?

In Tibetan Buddhism it's still possible, because i read their system on how to find the dead Dalai lama via a dream.

But based on my research, all experiment to communicate with the living one, which done by many famous people is failed.
For example:

- Ian Stevenson promised will tell a code of the safebox to all the worker colleagues. Failed!
- Houdini promise to do everything possible to communicate with his wife Bess Houdini. Also failed!
- The Beatles also doing this experiment: they promise whoever die first will contact the living one. Also failed.
- And many others

Answer (score 1):

According to Theravada, you will be reborn immediately after your death. So if you communicate, you are communicating with the new being.

Answer (score 1):

Good householder,

As Upasaka Sarath told and according to the truth and the Sublime Buddhas: after a breaking up of ones body, once giving up ones world, one (if not gained Arahatahood) reapears in the next world. So there are actually no death yet one does good to be reminded that very often be touched by former relative when listening, talking... and they, the death, are all around, some seen, some unseen.

Usually, untained mind, can only communicate in his common world, but it's not limited and possible to communicate even when "death", those former part of ones realm of existance, are fare or in other spheres of awarness.

Guess whom you are reading for now or why it was provided to met?

It's because of this that giving to and honor of ancestors plays a big role in traditional societies, for what one gives, one receives and you could be fast cut off and depend on gift of former relatives, having become a hungry ghost, even while alive. Current are ancestor times and it's by the giving of your former relatives toward the Sangha that you may gain this release here, if they would have done and to, it wouldn't meet you.

Don't neglegt the duties toward those before you and former beloved and supporter!

See also:

- [Offerings for hungry ghosts in Googleyana](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=1185.msg4765#msg4765)
- [Q&A Hungry ghosts and food offerings to the dead](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=8191.msg12987#msg12987)
- [Dhammavampire und hungrige Geister - Dhammavamps and hungry ghosts](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=1366.msg5719#msg5719)
- [P'chum Ben - Ahnengedenken / Honor of ancestors](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=819.msg2548#msg2548)

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchabge, other worldbinding trades but for escape from this wheel, of course also always dedicated as a share of those having fallen in missery states and bound, uncapable to move]*

Answer (score 0):

Death is not the end of story. There are various planes of existence. After death rebirth occurs in one of those planes of existence depending upon craving. Rebirth can be spontaneous or through a womb.Dead can communicate with us when we are asleep or in rare cases when we are awake.
Western science wants progress and for that they have sacrificed spirituality.  Do not expect science to confirm communication with dead ever.